# Redirect all Wordpress pages to SSL apart from one

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I want to redirect all pages on my Wordpress website to SSL apart from one.

I have tried numerous ways to do this and have succeessfully got the SSL working, but I cannot get the single page exclusion to work.

I am assuming the problem lies with the Wordpress specific rewrites.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^parent-page/child-page/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on   
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to not redirect `/parent-page/child-page/` ?

Comment: Exactly. I have added it after the Wordpress statements as I thought it wasn't working because the permalink hadn't been generated yet. Still didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always need your rules that redirect to be *before* the rules that internally rewrite. Otherwise, internal stuff (like `/index.php`) end up getting redirected.

Try:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/parent-page/child-page/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/parent-page/child-page/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on   
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Note that you also need to add a `/` leading slash to your `%{REQUEST_URI}` conditions, those will always start with a `/`. Additionally, you need to *not* redirect to https with that URI, so you need to add a negative exclusion condition to the redirect to https.

Comment: Thanks for this. Seems to be closer to my objective but the page in question just redirects to the homepage now.

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Comment: @Robert there's nothing in the rules that's redirecting to the home page, it maybe something else that's doing that.

Comment: I just removed everything else from he file but still having the same problem. Within Wordpress should I set the site URL to include HTTPS?

Comment: @Robert if you are setting up redirects from within Wordpress, it will not honor, or even be compatible, with redirects you put in htaccess. Neither wordpress or the rules in htaccess file are aware of each other.